# How do I make sure that systemd targets start after the last one has completed?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I have `t1.target` and `t2.target`. I want to ensure that `t2.target` is only started after `t1.target` and all it's dependency services are completed. I have mocked this up for now but it does not seem to work.

**t1.target**

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo.

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**t2.target**

```
[Unit]
Description=Bar.
After=t1.target
Wants=t1.target
Requires=t1.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**a.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/tmp/first.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=t1.target
PartOf=t1.target
```

**b.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/tmp/second.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=t2.target
PartOf=t2.target
```

Comment: Try moving `PartOf=` to the `[Unit]` section.  Only `RequiredBy=` and `WantedBy=` work in the `[Install]` section.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Still seems to start a and then start b and then end a and then end b. I would like it to be start a, end a, start b, end b, but based on the targets and not the services